# CompletableFuture vs ExectorService.submit()

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, completable-future

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable,
                                               Executor executor)
```

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the given executor after it runs the given action.

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one
> task will be active at any given time

I would like to use CompletableFuture to avoid having to use the blocking .get() Method, but I am unsure if the CompletableFuture can do this:

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one
> task will be active at any given time

by passing it `newSingleThreadExecutor()`.
i.e can Compleatable Future make use of the submit() Method of the ExecutorService, if not will this behavior above still be guaranteed because we are passing it executor that uses only one Thread.

To clarify the question further:

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

By passing the `newSingleThreadExecutor()` even if only the execute() Method is being called, will this still result in the Task being put in the `LinkedBlockingQueue` or  will the Task be executed from another Thread?

Why do I need this:

I am writing to a File and this writing should be performed asynchronously, but if the writing task is already running than, another attempt to write should not be started, also one should not read from a File while it is being written.

So if someone calls a method `readThisObjectFromFile(filename);` it should return CompletableFuture Object (here I would have to use `supplyAsync` Method) so that they can further do stuff like `thenApply` instead of having to use `.get()` Method and thus blocking the MainThread.

Comment: Since you don’t know when the next write (or read) will happen when you start a new write operation I am doubtful if CompletableFuture is the right tool here.

Comment: ok what do you suggest?

Comment: Each invocation of `newSingleThreadExecutor()` creates a new executor, so it is not sufficient to pass `newSingleThreadExecutor()`. You have to store the result of a single `newSingleThreadExecutor()` call into a variable and reuse it for all operations that are supposed to run on that single thread. This includes, `thenApplyAsync(…, executor)`. But when you create a chain of dependent actions, it wouldn’t be a problem if it used multiple threads, as still no dependent action is executed before the previous stage completed. But you must use it consistently.

Comment: "**But when you create a chain of dependent actions, it wouldn’t be a problem if it used multiple threads, as still no dependent action is executed before the previous stage completed. But you must use it consistently**" Thank you